# FileNotFoundError [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter, pyodbc

**Context:** I'm raising FileNotFound errors in a python script I'm working on. The desired output relies on 2 python functions & a proc in SQL Server. One function writes data to a json file, the other function is supposed to connect to the db & execute the proc which parses the content of the original json file & outputs a final .txt file which is then supposed to be opened via `os.startfile`

**Problem:** It seems there's an issue with the control flow or scope because the second function is unable to execute the proc & generate the output .txt file. But when I run the proc manually instead of through pyodbc it works.

**Question:** Can someone please help me understand how to resolve this issue?

**Python Functions:**

```
def execute_personnel_sp():
  username = REDACTED
  password = REDACTED

  personnel_connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=PC;"
                      "Database=mattermark_sandbox;"
                      "Username="+username+";"
                      "Password="+password+";"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
  personnel_cursor = personnel_connection.cursor()

  personnel_executesp = "EXEC get_personnel_data"
  personnel_connection.autocommit = True
  personnel_cursor.execute(personnel_executesp)

  print("Find your personnel leads data in this directory: C:\mattermark_etl_project\personnel_data.txt")
  personnel_connection.close()

  os.startfile(r'C:\mattermark_etl_project\personnel_data.txt')

def call_and_append_people(company_id):
  global company_id_data
  headers = {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer REDACTED'
     }
  url = 'https://api.mattermark.com/companies/'+ company_id_data + '/people?'
  response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
  with open(r'C:\mattermark_etl_project\personnel_data.json', 'a+', encoding="utf-8") as personnel_data:
    personnel_data.write('{}\n'.format(response.text))
  execute_personnel_sp()
```

**Proc snippet:**

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mattermark_sandbox.dbo.jsonparsed_personnel" QUERYOUT C:\mattermark_etl_project\personnel_data.txt -T -c'
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\etherealessence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "full_etl_app.py", line 105, in <lambda>
    get_personnel_leads_button = Button(f2, text="Get People Leads!", command=lambda:[get_company_id(company_id_ui),call_and_append_people(company_id_data)]).place(relx=0.13, rely=0.735, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.1)
  File "full_etl_app.py", line 227, in call_and_append_people
    execute_personnel_sp()
  File "full_etl_app.py", line 216, in execute_personnel_sp
    os.startfile(r'C:\mattermark_etl_project\personnel_data.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\mattermark_etl_project\\personnel_data.txt'
```

Comment: If you comment out the `personnel_cursor.execute(personnel_executesp)` and leave an old personnel_data.txt in the specified folder does `os.startfile` work in that case?

Comment: Whether ```personnel_cursor.exrcute(personnel_executesp)``` is commented out or not seems to make no difference because its not executing either way. When the line above is commented out & I generate the text file by manually running the proc then running ```os.startfile```it  runs fine.

Comment: So personnel_data.txt really doesn't exist because your Python app is unable to run the SP at all?

Comment: Correct. The app wont but the proc does when I run it manually. Maybe theres a limit to the number of concurrent connections pyodbc can support? The app connects & disconnects another instance prior so its not really a concurrent connection but maybe its related?

Comment: Is your Python app connecting with the same credentials that you use when you run the SP manually (via SSMS or whatever)? `xp_cmdshell` does have security restrictions on it, so perhaps they may be preventing your app from running the SP. If so, I would expect to see something in the ERRORLOG about it.

Comment: Its the same credentials, I dont see an errors in the sql server transaction log that appear to be related

Comment: Your `bcp` command has no `-S` or `-d` parameters. Are you really connecting to the default instance of SQL Server on your local machine and the default database for the SQL login you are using?

Comment: Same issue occurs when I pass the ```-S``` param. Any other ideas?

Comment: I dunno, I just tried it and it worked for me using Python 3.7.3 and pyodbc 4.0.27.

Comment: Which param did you use?

Comment: `exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.jsonparsed_personnel" QUERYOUT C:\__tmp\personnel_data.txt -T -c -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d myDb'`

Comment: So when you say the BCP command worked do you mean it worked when you execute it directly or when you embed it in a proc and try to execute that proc via pyodbc?

Comment: Embedded in an SP and then executing the SP from Python using `crsr.execute` immediately followed by `os.startfile`.